# How to calculate a mouse position like 0 will return -8 and 1000 will return 8 number?

Tags: javascript, animation, math

As I'm trying to get into animation using a **mousemove event** I encountered a problem on how to get the **specific number** with a limit in both **left and right** direction while moving the mouse event

like if the mouse position is in **500** inside a container of **1000** width a function **should return 0**

**Also on How to reverse the return like if it's on 0 it should return 8**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Mouse Move</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus, 
    magni.
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  color: #2c3e50;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

JS:

```
const CARD_CONTAINER = document.querySelector('.container');
let window_width = window.innerWidth;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  let getTranslateX = (event.clientX / window_width) * 8;

  console.log(getTranslateX);

  CARD_CONTAINER.style.transform = `translateX(-${getTranslateX}px)`;
});
```

Comment: What element is registered to the mousemove event? Also, you need to post some actual JavaScript as a [mcve] before your question is closed.

Comment: So, 0 is -8 and 1000 is +8. that would normally mean that 500 is 0 not 4!

Comment: Yeah I forgot that updating the question now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ANIMATION_WIDTH=1000;
const RANGE=8;
const result=(mousePosition-(ANIMATION_WIDTH/2))*RANGE/(ANIMATION_WIDTH/2);
```

Comment: Is there a way to reverse if the mouse position is 0 it will return 8 and if it's on 1000 it will return -8? Thanks man kudos to you

Comment: use the negative: `const result=-(mousePosition-(ANIMATION_WIDTH/2))*RANGE/(ANIMATION_WIDTH/2);` or invert position inside parentheses `const result=((ANIMATION_WIDTH/2)-mousePosition)*RANGE/(ANIMATION_WIDTH/2);` @Vince